# No input file specified plesk server4you

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I transfered my website to a new dedicated server which is CENTOS and PHP Version 5.3.3 with PLESK.

My problem is this, I'm getting "No input file specied" error in everypage expect homepage.  Firstly i think it's a chmod problem than i set it to 755 to all folders and files in httpdocs

Secondly googled and find a solution about .htaccess

My .htaccess is:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage tr-TR
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And i changed

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

By this changes site started to work in a different way. There wasn't any error but in everypage i am redirecting to homepage.

```
Hovewer when i write index.php into the url as guncebektas.com/index.php/yaptiklarim
```

I can reach the page that i want

Than, I changed php.ini, `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` nothing changed than Finally i decided to write here, thanks for your help.

```
Site : guncebektas.com/  
A page : guncebektas.com/yaptiklarim  
I can reach : guncebektas.com/index.php/yaptiklarim
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that it's about fastcgi problem, i changed it to apache module from plesk control panel - PHP support (Run PHP as apache module)

Now it's working

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into the same issue and it wasnt an option for me to use mod_php instead of fast-cgi.

Simply had to fix permissions using :

```
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 0755 '{}' \;
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 0644 '{}' \;
```

Everything went smooth after that.